# TableOperation exists in two DLLs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am developing an app for Windows Azure and just started using azure table storage using version 2.1.0.4 (the newest version is not supported by the storage simualtor yet) of the storage API. When I now try to execute a `TableOperation` like:

```
cloudTable.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(entity));
```

I get the following exception:

> The type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation' exists in both 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll' and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.StorageUtility.dll'

**How can I get that to work?**
Am I using an incompatible version of Diagnostics (it is from the Azure SDK 2.2)?

Comment: One quick comment regarding `the newest version is not supported by the storage simualtor yet` - If you download storage emulator version 2.2.1, it has support for storage library 3.x. More info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/01/27/windows-azure-storage-emulator-2-2-1-preview-release-with-support-for-2013-08-15-version.aspx. Even though it is in preview but I have been using it since it was released and I encountered no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it did not help with my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer, I work at Microsoft on the team that delivers the Storage SDK libraries.

The diagnostics library uses a special sub package to avoid any version collisions with the users selected storage sdk dependency. To do this they essentially IL inject the storage library and its dependencies (odatalib) into this utility dll. However these types are marked as internal so you should not be seeing this compiler error as the internal types should be hidden from you. I attempted to repro this by creating a new cloud project using SDK 2.2 and adding a reference to the StorageUtility.dll you mentioned and did not receive a similar compiler error when using storage types. Can you provide more information on your repro, project setup etc.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I will provide a demo project as soon as I get home, as I have it there, but I do NOT get a compiler error. I get this as a runtime error, when I access the page.

Comment: I now tried it again a few times and the error is gone - no idea why, I did not change anything in that project as it was just a test...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I used the external alias feature:
[Having problems when two of referenced assemblies both define type A.A1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272907/having-problems-when-two-of-referenced-assemblies-both-define-type-a-a1)

But I would still like a "nice solution"...